# Why is there an /index folder that doesn't actually exist, and how to get rid of it

Tags: google-index, apache2, document-root

I feel embarrassed asking this question because I've been doing this so long, but I guess you're never too old to learn.

Environment is Rocky Linux 8.8, Virtualmin Pro 7.7, Apache 2.4.37, PHP 8.1 (FPM). Site is hand-coded if that matters. Every page is its own php file and they all live in the Web root, which is (/public_html)/.

The problem became apparent in Google Search Console, where Google was choosing "duplicate" pages in a non-existent /index directory as canonical. In other words, they would choose

```
https://example.com/index/index.php
https://example.com/index/someotherpage.php
etc.
```

Instead of

```
https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/someotherpage.php
etc.
```

I figured it was just the usual Google weirdness until I manually accessed the pages in the non-existent /index directory (yes, I checked, and it didn't exist) with a browser, and they came up, albeit with no styling and no JavaScript because the paths to the stylesheets and scripts are relative.

What I eventually did (just a few minutes ago, so it's too soon to know whether Google accepts it) is created an /index directory and placed an .htaccess file in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That redirects the requests to the root when I use it in a browser. I have no idea whether Google with have issues with it.

Why is there an /index directory that doesn't (or didn't) actually exist? Shouldn't requests to a non-existent directory just throw a 404? Or is this some new thing because so few people hand-code anymore that /index is assumed to be the Web root instead of / ?

EDIT 1

.htaccess for the root of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirects from example.com to example.aero
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.aero/$1 [L,R=301]

# removes www
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 401 https://example.aero/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.aero/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.aero/404.php

# GZIP compression for text files: HTML, CSS, JS, Text, XML, fonts
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>

<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|swf|webp)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch ".(xml|txt|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

The canonical domain is on the .aero TLD, but I also own the .com and redirect it .aero.

The previously-mentioned .htaccess file in /index/ is the only thing in that directory, which did not exist until I created it to try to fix this issue. I am wondering if I shouldn't change it to redirect all requests on that directory to the site's 404 page?

EDIT 2

Based on MrWhite's comment, I checked and found that `MultiViews` is in fact enabled in the Apache configuration, presumably by Virtualmin as a default. I don't want to mess with it because there may be some reason it's enabled; but disabling the option in `.htaccess` for the root of the domain corrects the behavior and causes requests on files in `/index/` to return the 404 page.

I will make that change in this site and others affected by the same issue while I further explore why `MultiViews` is enabled in Apache. I don't want to disable it system-wide until I know why it was enabled in the first place. There may be a good reason.

Comment: I'm not sure this question can be answered with bespoke code.  What does your .htaccess say (if it exists?)   Is there any load-balancer being used?

Comment: To clarify, a request for `/index/someotherpage.php` actually serves`/someotherpage.php` (from the root) and not `/index.php`? The later would happen if `MultiViews` had been enabled (perhaps in the server config). However, how did Google find these URLs in the first place (that suggests some other misconfig)? "Or is this some new thing" - nope.

Comment: Requests for any files in the previously-nonexistent /index/ directory served the pages from that directory, and made all the links relative to itself (that is, in the /index/ directory), but without styling or scripts. I created the /index/ directory and added the .htaccess file within it with the single directive to redirect to the root, which is working. I have no idea why that was even necessary, but I'm going to check the Apache config. Maybe Virtualmin enabled MultiViews during the Apache setup.

Comment: `MultiViews` was in fact the problem, MrWhite. I have edited my question with the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by MrWhite, MultiViews being enabled server-wide in the Apache configuration was in fact the problem. I've disabled it in `.htaccess` for now, and the non-existent pages are now through 404'S as they should. Hopefully this will eliminate Google treating them as duplicates.

I suppose someone posted a bad link to the site at some point and Google followed it. There's no internal link pointing to the non-existent directory.